# Uninstalled running kernel. Machine still up, but afraid to reboot

Tags: apt, grub2, kernel, reboot

Ok, I know just enough to be dangerous, and I screwed up. I need help recovering.

My Ubuntu 16.04 warned me that /boot was full. I googled and learned to remove old kernels.  I dumbly did not do a `uname -r` first, so assumed that the highest number was current (4.4.0-91-generic) and removed the rest, including 4.4.0-89-generic).

I then, just in time, did `uname -r` and learned that I'm currently still using -89.

I tried to install `linux-image-generic`:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-image-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.91.96).
linux-image-generic set to manually installed.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

I assume that I need to:

- verify that my -91 kernel is complete
- Configure to boot from it

Help?

Comment: Did you upgrade the system before doing this? If you booted with 89, then upgraded to 91, the system may already be configured to boot from 91 in the next reboot.

Comment: I did not manually update.  I assume that a auto-update triggered this problem.

I hope you are correct. But, I'm afraid to test by rebooting, without first verifying. How can I check this before actually booting?

Comment: I'm feeling a bit better already:

1) I've prepared a fresh USB startup disk, just in case

2) I've grepped /boot/grub/grub.cfg for "4\.4" and verified that it mentions 4.4.0-91 many times, and never mentions 4.4.0-89.


What else can I check before attempting a boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Most likely*, it will be fine to ((optionally) utter a small supplication and) reboot. As suggested in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945234/uninstalled-kernel-machine-still-up-but-afraid-to-reboot/945248#comment1501772_945234) by Katu, most likely there was an update since you last booted, and that's why you're not using the latest kernel.

However, I'd strongly recommend you reinstall the running kernel:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

And reinstall the 91 kernel to ensure it is complete:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic
```

Running either of these commands will trigger an `update-grub` and regeneration of the initramfs, configuring the system to boot from the latest possible kernel installed.

It's advisable to have an extra kernel, just in case of any issues.

Next time you want to clean up, please use `sudo apt autoremove` which cleanly removes all but the latest two kernels, and next time you install Ubuntu, consider not making a separate `/boot` partition :)

Comment: Thanks!!

re not having a separate /boot partition, add me to the amen gallery.  But, this was created by a default Ubuntu install, and I did not know any better.  Arggh!

Can you point me to instructions of how to remove or grow the /boot partition on my running system?

Comment: I just did the --reinstall of -91.

A bunch of output generated, which I won't paste into this comment.

One line looked worrisome: "grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map."  Is this an issue?

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb hmm o.O that is worrisome. I will investigate. You can paste the output [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com)

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb we'll need the link to it, if you want us to look ;) did you try installing the current kernel?

Comment: Oops, my bad.

Here it is.  I included a bit more too, that may be helpful.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25289045/

Comment: And, yes, I did install the current kernel too.  Got the same warning line.  All in the pastebin.

Comment: That's awesome @DavidGoldfarb thanks a lot! The error is about `/dev/sda` but your `/boot` and `/boot/efi` partitions are on `/dev/sdb`. I cannot find `/dev/sda` in your `df` output and I am wondering why your `/` is mounted on `/dev/mapper/ubuntu...` Do you have a file `/boot/grub/device.map`? If so, what does it contain? (sorry if I missed it in pasted output)

Comment: I don't have any file /boot/grub/device.map.  Here is the directory and contents of grub.cfg, fwiw: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25289108/.

Comment: I don't know why / is mounted on /dev/mapper/ubuntu.   I knew a lot less about Ubuntu when I setup this machine last year. I think I just followed all the defaults.   Physically, the machine has only one drive, a 512GB SSD.

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb I can't understand why `grub-probe` is worried about `/dev/sda1`. I read many things about this error, but they were mostly about it being a bug, and/or preventing people from installing GRUB. If I understood the `/dev/mapper` mounting I would tell you to go ahead and reboot and at worst you can `set root` in the GRUB command line, but as it is I am nervous, although the refs to `hd1,gpt2` in your `grub.cfg` are encouraging. The file looks fine and the output from `update-grub` seems to indicate that it was otherwise successful.

Comment: I've not tried rebooting yet. (I'm waiting for an unrelated process to finish in a VM) but I'm now feeling more comfortable; thanks!

It looks like sda was the USB key where I created the startup disk an hour ago. It was listed as such in gparted, and the install warning went away when I tried again now after removing the key.

I suppose that my filesystem was initially installed on sdb, because I had also started from a USB key last and, presumably, it was mapped the same way.

Does this seem plausible? Does it expalin /dev/mapper too?

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb oh yes, that's a reasonable explanation for the `grub-probe` error. I didn't get that error when I deleted my running kernel and reinstalled it as a test, but I didn't expect to and I assumed it was something about your system config... `/dev/mapper/` is set as root in your `grub.cfg`. If you've run `sudo update-grub` since removing the USB key, I'd say there's no reason to worry about it.

Comment: I rebooted.  All good.   Running -91 now.  Amusingly, the first reboot warned me about a system problem. Clicking the link took me to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/798414.  (well, duh!).  Second reboot was clean, and all is good now. Thank you for the help and hand-holding.

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb great to hear :D

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb re. resizing partitions - risky business. If the installer created it, maybe there was a good reason. Since `/boot` is only 15% full now, it's probably big enough to manage. I recommend running `sudo apt autoremove` after every kernel update

Comment: Will do. Thx again!

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb Running `sudo apt autoremove` will not remove the two kernels you installed manually according to this answer. You would have to mark them automatically installed by `sudo apt-mark auto`; see the respective manual page.

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb you could also mark linux-image-generic auto as it used to be by same way: `sudo apt-mark auto linux-image-generic`. (linux-generic is still manually installed.) To make removing extra kernels automatic, you could setup unattended-upgrades as recommended in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels#Automatic_Maintenance

Comment: Hmm, I did already have automatic updates setup and I'm running 16.04. If I understand that page correctly, that should have been all that was needed.  So, I don't really understand why the old kernels had accumulated.